# Is it possible to output a collection without having an entirely separate model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The Contoso university gave this as an example:

How do I append this code to allow me to output the `ICollection` attribute of `Instructor`

```
  public class Instructor : Person
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
    }
}
public class Course
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Number")]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 5)]
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the view that outputs the instructor details:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Instructor

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Instructor</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OfficeAssignment.Location)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OfficeAssignment.Location)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HireDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HireDate)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: Well, there's multiple courses, so a loop over `Model.Courses` seems like a good idea.

Comment: but I cant just say model.courses can I? Dont I need some sort of a view model or a query?

Comment: ahhh I see.... I thought it was going to make me use some sort of view model or something. I didn't dream that it would be that straight forward. Question. What is the difference between Model and model??? I do not understand where that is coming from because @model at the top is a lower case.

Comment: Model is the actual object that holds the data and `model` is just an instance of the `Model`. Try changing it to anything else like `m`, `x` and it should still work.

Comment: `@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Instructor` declares the type of your model. `@Model` accesses the current instance of the model. `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstMidName)` is creating a lambda expression where the parameter to be passed in is captured in `model`, but any other word would work there. This would do the same thing `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstMidName)`

Comment: You *could* create a partial view that accepts an `IEnumerable<Course>` if you wanted to decrease the amount of code in your view or if you had a need to display multiple courses in a similar manner elsewhere.

Comment: Beware that since you're using an ICollection to obtain the courses, this will probably cause data access logic to be triggered in the view. If you're concerned about this, it might be better to create view models that are separate from the Entity Framework models, and then create a mapping from the EF models to the view models.

Comment: So another question on this. I see that this is how to output the collection from the model, but How do I save it back to the model? That is where I am stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

All that I had to do was exactly this...

```
 @{
        foreach (var course in Model.Courses)
        {
            <dd>
                @course.Title
            </dd>
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you don't want to edit the datas outputed then yeah... this is ok